# Unity C++ DLL performance drop in Standalone Build vs. Editor mode

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, unity-game-engine, dll

## Abstract

I am building an unmanaged C++ Dll plugin for a Unity project, where the plugin interfaces with 2 sensor APIs, runs a repeating sensor fusion algorithm, and returns the final results via a callback function. The project runs on Windows 10 64bit. Everything was running smoothly inside the Unity Editor until I tried to build the Unity project to a standalone version. In the **build** mode, the sensor fusion algorithm loop had constant "hiccups" where the execution time will constantly increase 10x in one or two iterations.

I do not expect answers that could directly solve my problem as the issue probably is case specific, but I hope someone with experience could share some insights on what could be wrong. I have experimented with things I mentioned in the later section.

## Relevant pseudo-code

#### Dll functions:

```
extern "C" {
    void start(FilterWrapper *& pWrapper, Callback cb) {
        pWrapper = new FilterWrapper();
        // code registers callback
    }

    void stop(FilterWrapper *& pWrapper) {
        pWrapper->stopFilter();
        delete pWrapper;
        pWrapper = NULL;
    }
}
```

#### FilterWrapper Class

```
Class FilterWrapper
{
public:
    FilterWrapper();
    ~FilterWrapper();
    void stopFilter();

private:
    void sampleSensor1();
    void sampleSensor2();
    void processData();
    void runAlgorithm();

    bool stop_condition = false;
    std::thread thread1,thread2,thread3,thread4;
    std::deque<float> bufferA,bufferB,bufferC;
    std::mutex mtxA,mtxB,mtxC;
};

FilterWrapper::FilterWrapper() {
    thread1 = std::thread(&FilterWrapper::sampleSensor1,this);
    thread2 = std::thread(&FilterWrapper::sampleSensor2,this);
    thread3 = std::thread(&FilterWrapper::processData,this);
    thread4 = std::thread(&FilterWrapper::runAlgorithm,this);
}

void FilterWrapper::stopFilter() {
    stop_condition = true;
    if (thread1.joinable()) thread1.join();
    // same for other threads ...
}

void FilterWrapper::sampleSensor1() {
    while(!stop_condition) {
        // code sample data
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxA);
        bufferA.push_back(data);
    }
}

void FilterWrapper::sampleSensor2() {
    while(!stop_condition) {
        // code sample data
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxB);
        bufferB.push_back(data);
    }
}

void FilterWrapper::processData() {
    while(!stop_condition) {
        float data;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxA);
            if (bufferA.empty()) continue;
            data = bufferA.front();
            bufferA.pop_front();
        }

        // code process data...

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxC);
        bufferC.push_back(data);
    }
}

void FilterWrapper::runAlgorithm() {
    while(!stop_condition) {
        float data1, data2;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxB);
            if (bufferB.empty()) continue;
            data1 = bufferB.front();
            bufferB.pop_front();
        }
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtxC);
            if (bufferC.empty()) continue;
            data1 = bufferC.front();
            bufferC.pop_front();
        }

        std::chrono::stead_clock::time_point t_start = std::chrono::stead_clock::now();
        // run the algorithm with data1 and data2 ...
        std::chrono::stead_clock::time_point t_end = std::chrono::stead_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float,std::milli> dur = t_end-t_start;
        std::cout << "algorithm time: "  << dur.count() << "\n";
    }
 }
```

## Project Structure

1. Inside the DLL

   - A *FilterWrapper* Class whose instance will initialize and manage:

     - Sensor1 sampling thread - a producer thread, store data in FIFO buffer A
     - Sensor2 sampling thread - a producer thread, store data in FIFO buffer B
     - Sensor data processing thread -  process the raw data from the buffer A and queue the results in a FIFO buffer C
     - Algorithm thread -  a consumer thread, take data out of FIFO buffer B&C and run the algorithm
     - All threads will run while loops with a stop condition
   - Functions to export

     - an *initialize(FilterWrapper *& pWrapper, Callback cb)* function - to create a *FilterWrapper* object via *new* and pass the pointer out, and pass in the callback function.
     - a *stop(FilterWrapper *& pWrapper)* function - to set stop conditions for all threads in the *FilterWrapper* object and free the pointer using *delete*.
2. On Unity side

   - Import the *initialize()* and *stop()* functions using [DllImport("MyDLL")]
   - Call *initialize()* in *Awake()* and pass in the callback function
   - Call *stop()* in *OnApplicationQuit()*
   - Use a private *IntPtr pWrapper* to hold the reference to the *FilterWrapper* object passed out by *initialize()*.

## Problem

I first developed and verified the algorithm and multithreading in a C++ console application project then copy over the classes and functions to a DLL project and wrote the *FilterWrapper* Class. In the C++ console application as well as the Unity Editor mode, the execution time of each iteration in algorithm loop is consistently around 9 ms, and that of each iteration in sensor data processing loop is 12 ms. However, when the Unity project is built, the execution times could frequently spike to 30 ms and 90 ms respectively.

## Things I Have Done So Far

1. allocate a console window in the DLL such that I can monitor the debug information.
2. use std::chrono::steady_clock to time the execution; data is retrieved at the beginning of loops so that the time of waiting to acquire locks is NOT counted.
3. use std::lock_guard and std::mutex to ensure safe access to buffers.
4. start a clean Unity project with default scene, and the only addition is attaching the C# script that imports and calls the DLL; leave all Build setting as default; ensure the latest DLL build is copied into the Plugin folder.
5. experiment with process and thread priorities: set process priority to HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS (one level below real-time priority to avoid affecting system stability) and set thread priority to THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST (despite the name, also one level below time-critical priority).
6. experiment with manually setting thread affinity (I am desperate); distribute each thread to one logical processor (I do have enough logical processors).
7. run both editor and standalone build long enough to ensure consistent observation.
8. in DLL, comment out the algorithm code and replace it with code just dynamically allocating a large byte array (uint8_t *pByteArr = new uint8_t[1200000]), memcpy() some garbage to it and deallocate it (delete[] pByteArr). In Editor mode, it takes roughly 0.18 ms on my machine. In the standalone build, it frequently spikes to 5 ms.

## Summary

The C++ portion of code runs fine in either console application or Unity Editor mode when imported as DLL, but very unstable and slow when the Unity project is built to the standalone application. As people often say the Editor mode runs a lot of overhead, one would expect the performance is typically better when the project is built. It seems my case the quite the opposite. I have ruled out the graphics issue since there is really nothing in the Unity scene, and I am thinking there are some environment factors that change when the project is built, but I am not sure where to look.

Comment: I think I may have some clues for the performance drops. In the Editor mode, all the Unity Engine stuff is loaded, but in the standalone, extra computational power is needed at the beginning of the application to load Unity stuff. Meanwhile, my algorithm is time critical that all the buffered data has to be matched and processed in time, so the initial slow down caused by loading Unity stuff created some kind of ripple effect. Adding extra waiting time after the standalone starts and before loading my dll seems to help.